# Как проверить наличие элемента в JSON ? Python

Tags: python-3.x, json

Есть файл `db.json`

Его содержание:

```
[
  {
    "user": "981"
  },
  {
    "user": "859"
  },
  {
    "user": "237"
  }
]
```

Например нужно проверить есть ли `"user": "859"` в `db.json`

Как делаю это я:

```
import json

def json_read(file_name):
    try:
        json_data = json.load(open(file_name, 'r', encoding="cp1251"))
    except:
        json_data = []
    return json_data

data = json_read("db.json")
user_in_db = "859"

for user in data:
    if user_in_db == user['user']:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Но я думаю в случае большого количества пользователей в `db.json` данный способ менее удобен. Есть ли какой то более удобный и быстрый способ сделать это ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
In [13]: db = [
    ...:   {
    ...:     "user": "981"
    ...:   },
    ...:   {
    ...:     "user": "859"
    ...:   },
    ...:   {
    ...:     "user": "237"
    ...:   }
    ...: ]

In [14]: {'user': '859'} in db
Out[14]: True
```

Или:

```
In [15]: any(x['user'] == '859' for x in db)
Out[15]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = json.load(open('db.json', 'r'))

dictValueKey = dict([ [d.get(k),k] for k in d for d in data])

print("Yes" if dd.get("859")=="user" else "No")
Yes
print("Yes" if dd.get("111")=="user" else "No")
No
print("Yes" if dd.get("859")=="userNo" else "No")
No
```